# Restricting content based on visitor’s location - EE3

Tags: ip, iptonation

I’m looking for a way to hide certain content on an ExpressionEngine 3 site if the visitor is outside the UK.

I thought I might be able to use IP to Nation, but this proved not to be the case.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an IP plugin but it doesn't look like any of them have been updated to v3 yet. You could try contacting the authors of, for example,

- https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ipgeobase
- https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ipgeo
- https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ert-freegeoip
- https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/geoip-access

and ask if they have plans to update, or it might not be that difficult to do yourself. You might be able to just add the addon.setup.php and be good to go.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Tyssen - I’ll see if I can get in touch with those developers.